# virtuemart 2.0 change default order status pending to confirmed

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

i'm Using Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 2.26d. When the purchase is confirmed default order status will be "Pending" by default. But I want to change default order status will be "Confirmed".

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Virtuemart administration panel at all? It is in the options there... Also the payment plugins have settings for this btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Order status based on the Payment Status in VM,

```
Go to admin -> Virtuemart ->Shops -> Payment Methods -> Edit the payment method.
```

You will get three options.

- Order Status for Pending transactions
- Order Status for Successful transactions
- Order Status for Failed transactions.

Set the proper order status from your Dropdown.
Also you can add new Order status from

```
Admin->  Virtuemart -> Configuration -> Order Status.
```

Hope it helps..